# add dynamic row based on user selection

Tags: javascript, php, html

```html
<label>
  <input  type="radio" name="optradio" >1 PERSON
</label>
<label>
  <input  type="radio" name="optradio" >2 PERSON
</label>
<label>
  <input  type="radio" name="optradio" >3 PERSON
</label>

<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped mah">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Name" class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email"></div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Currently, one input is there. If a user selects a 2 person or 3 person radio button we need to display 2 or 3 input field will display, adding row dynamically based on user selection

Answer (score 2):

Here simple use loop and put html in container :

```
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="1">1 
 PERSON
</label>
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="2" >2 
PERSON
</label>
<label>
<input  type="radio" name="optradio" value="3" >3 
PERSON
</label>

<div class="table-responsive">
<table class="table table-hover table-striped mah">
<tbody id="container">

  </tbody>
 </table>
  </div>
```

and use jquery loop for simply creating dynamic content:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').click( function(){
$val = $(this).val();
$('#container').html('');
$content = '';
var i = 1;
for( i = 0; i < $val; i++ ) {
    $content += '<tr><td><div class="form-group"><input type="text" name="f1-email" placeholder="Name" class="f1-email form-control" id="f1-email"></div></td></tr>';
}
   $('#container').html($content);
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: in my website i am not able to use value 1 for the radio button , because the each radio button having the tour amount as value, <label><input class="price-input" type="radio"  name="optradio" value="4700">  
               1 PERSON - <b>Cost Rs.<span class="price">4700</span>/- </b>
               </label>

Comment: If your value is dynamic, you can use any attribute for input e.g. <input type="radio" count="1"  value="xyz"/>. I think you are dynamically populating the inputs so in logic in place of value you can use $val = $(this).attr('count'). it will give the value of attribute and rest is explained above. Good luck.Let me know if anything pop's up. @Prabhu

Comment: thanks for your replay, it will working fine, how to send dynamically created text field to my mail after submitting the form...how i assign name and id field for that

Comment: Kindly create a new question for this , there i can answer more freely and can get more idea what you actually want to do. Here not enough information in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a nice example at CodePen for you.

See the Pen [Radio Inputs](https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity/pen/qQYjNM/) by Animated Creativity ([@animatedcreativity](https://codepen.io/animatedcreativity)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

- All elements are created dynamically using a dummy HTML element. Please edit the dummy HTML element, to make any changes to the input elements.
- You can provide number of elements to be added.
- Script also triggers the provided callback so that you can do related things when number of inputs are changed.
- You can access the dynamically created elements using result object's elements property. Please check the example below.

Example usage:

`var result = new radioInputs(5, document.querySelector(".radio-inputs"), function(count) {
  console.log(count, result.elements);
});`